# Assert Error is thrown when mocking python3

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to write a test that mocks raising `PermissionError` on a call to `open()` when attempting to open a file for reading. However I cannot seem to get the test working. The `PermissionError` appears to be thrown but my test fails because of this even though I am trying to assert it is thrown.

Below contains one of my attempts:

**fileMethods.py**

```
def readfile(myfile):
    with open(myfile, 'r') as file:
        filecontent = file.read()
    file.close()
    return filecontent
```

**fileMethods_test.py**

```
def test_readfile_throws_PermissionError(self):
    with mock.patch('fileMethods.open') as openMock:
        openMock.side_effect = PermissionError
        self.assertRaises(PermissionError, fileMethods.readfile('file_to_readin'))
```

Am I missing something obvious or is the way I am testing this method incorrect?

Comment: Either you open a file with `with` OR you close it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this will not work is because you are mocking `fileMethods.open` and so the `open` function (which raises the `PermissionError` you're looking for) is not even called.

If the `open` function is mocked (and therefore, the called function will do nothing), you can't assert that the exception raised by that function is called.

The way it works is that when you mock a function it will, by default, not do anything. Look into the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) which explains this in further depth.

Comment: So have I reference the wrong open then in the mock? And how would I go about testing the `readFile` method?